# Simple way to add double quote in a JSON String

Tags: java, json, string, spring, double-quotes

I am trying to write something that returns some [search suggestion](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions/1.1) result.

Suppose I have an string like this :

```
"[Harry,[harry potter,harry and david]]"
```

The format is like [A_STRING,A_STRING_ARRAY_HERE].

But I wany the output format to be like

```
[ "Harry",["harry potter","harry and david"]]
```

so that I can put it into the HTTP Response Body.

Is there a simple way to do this, I don't want to add "" for a very single String from scratch .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo

```
String text = "[Harry,[harry potter,harry and david]]";
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\[\\],]+", "\"$0\"");

System.out.println(text);
```

Output: `["Harry",["harry potter","harry and david"]]`

---

Explanation:
If I understand you correctly you want to surround series of all non-`[`-and-`]`-and-`,` characters with double quotes. In that case you can simply use `replaceAll` method with regex `([^\\[\\],]+)` in which which

- `[^\\[\\],]` - represents one non character which is not `[` or `]` or `,` (comma)
- `[^\\[\\],]+` - `+` means that element before it can appear *one or more times*, in this case it represents one or more characters which are not `[` or `]` or `,` (comma)

Now in replacement we can just surround match from [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 0 (entire match) represented by `$0` with double brackets `"$0"`. BTW since `"` is metacharacter in String (it is used to start and end string) we need to escape it if we want to create its literal. To do so we need to place `\` before it so at the end it String representing `"$0"` needs to be written as `"\"$0\""`.

For more clarification about group 0 which `$0` uses (quote from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

> There is also a special group, group 0, which always represents the entire expression.

Comment: Thank you! I will test more for this and accept your answer if it works for all my case, would you please explain why `"\"$0\""` is like this, U an not very understand what it means, would you please update in your answer?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what part of my answer is unclear? "*why "\"$0\"" is like this*" doesn't say what you don't understand. If it is why there is ``\`` before each `"` then I explained (I think) it in my answer. If it is about `$0` then you would need to read some regex tutorial (I linked few good ones in my answer) which will explain you concept of groups, so you will see that group 0 is similar to group 1 in case of regex `(somePattern)`, in other words it holds entire match.

Answer (score 0):

If the format `[A_STRING,A_STRING_ARRAY_HERE]` is consistent, provided that there are no commas in any of the strings, then you can use the comma as a delimiter and then add the double quotes accordingly. For example:

```
public String format(String input) {
    String[] d1 = input.trim().split(",", 2);
    String[] d2 = d1[1].substring(1, d1[1].length() - 2).split(",");
    return "[\"" + d1[0].substring(1) + "\",[\"" + StringUtils.join(d2, "\",\"") + "\"]]";
}
```

Now if you call `format()` with the string `"[Harry,[harry potter,harry and david]]"`, it would return the result you want. Not that I used the `StringUtils` class from Apache Commons Lang library to join the String arrays back together with a delimiter. You can do the same with your own custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of program works (you can optimize it):

```
//...
String str = "[Harry,[harry potter,harry and david]]";

public String modifyData(String str){

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '[' && str.charAt(i + 1) == '[') {
            strBuilder.append("[");
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == '[' && str.charAt(i + 1) != '[') {
            strBuilder.append("[\"");
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ']' && str.charAt(i - 1) != ']') {
            strBuilder.append("\"]");
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ']' && str.charAt(i - 1) == ']') {
            strBuilder.append("]");
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ',' && str.charAt(i + 1) == '[') {
            strBuilder.append("\",");
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ',' && str.charAt(i + 1) != '[') {
            strBuilder.append("\",\"");
        } else {
            strBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
return strBuilder.toString();
}
```